# Comunicacion serie uart

Tags: c, serialport

Tengo un problema al recibir y enviar mediante un puerto serie. La comunicación se realiza desde PC a micro STM32.
Desde el PC le mando un 0x80 y en el micro recibo 0x01, le mando un 0x81 y recibo 0xBF.
Si la comunicación es, al contrario, desde el micro le mando un 0x80 y recibo un 0x01, le mando un 0x81 y recibo 0xBF.
Como se observa, la comunicación es coherente, respecto a que el error se produce tanto en el envió como en la recepción.
Este es parte del código:

```
char in[8];
memset(in,NULL,sizeof(in));
HAL_UART_Receive(&huart1, (uint8_t *)in, 1, 100);
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*) in, 1, 1); //lo mando a display
in[0]=0x81;
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t*) in,1, 1);  //retorno a PC
HAL_Delay(200);
```

Configuracion del puerto comunicacion con PC:

```
 /* USART1 init function */
    static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void) 
   {
    huart1.Instance = USART1;
    huart1.Init.BaudRate = 19200;
    huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
   {
   _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }
}
```

La configuracion del puerto serie (com8) es la misma, 19200 baudios, 8 bits sin paridad.

Comment: asi a primeras parece cosa de la velocidad de transmision o la codificacion de paquetes, como si fuera distinta entre PC y micro. Puedes mostrar la configuracion de `huart1` ?

Comment: El problema es que el emisor trabaja en logica negada y, ademas, el orden de transmision es LSB to MSB. o dicho de otra manera, faltaba el driver rs232 en el hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Al suceder lo mismo en ida o vuelta (PC -> micro o micro -> PC), evidentemente el problema es logico o de empaquetamiento. Seria util enviar comandos en orden binario creciente (0,1,10,11,100,101, etc) para poder evaluar mejor segun la respuesta obtenida.